# Python - Pandas, Datetime - Convert datetime entries over 3 date columns into month values (i.e. 2022-05-26 to month value of 5 (may) )

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

Having trouble converting datetime entries to month values over 3 columns in my dataframe.

What i have tried is writing a lambda function:
`lambda x: x.strftime('%m') if isinstance(x , datetime.datetime) else x`

and using .apply to apply it:
`df.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%m') if isinstance(x , datetime.datetime) else x)`

I seem to be getting no change to my dataset.

desired outcome is to go from this:

| date 1 | date 2 | date 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-26 00:00:00 | 2022-05-31 00:00:00 | 2022-06-05 00:00:00 |
| 2022-06-01 00:00:00 | 2022-06-13 00:00:00 | 2022-07-05 00:00:00 |

to this:

| date 1 | date 2 | date 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05 | 05 | 06 |
| 06 | 06 | 07 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) per columns in lambda function in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: x.dt.strftime('%m'))
print (df1)
  date 1 date 2 date 3
0     05     05     06
1     06     06     07
```

Your solution is possible if elementwise use lambda function in [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html), but it is not vectorized:

```
df1 = df.applymap(lambda x: x.strftime('%m') if isinstance(x , pd.Timestamp) else x)
```

If need months names:

```
df2 = df.apply(lambda x: x.dt.month_name())
print (df2)
  date 1 date 2 date 3
0    May    May   June
1   June   June   July
```

Answer (score 1):

Would you try this?

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col]).dt.strftime('%m')
print(df)

  date1 date2 date3
0    05    05    06
1    06    06    07
```